# How to check the stack of the Pgm in AS/400 RPG?

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg, cl

I have a doubt about how to find the stack of the pgm?

EX: 
 We have three pgms PGM 1 , PGM 2, PGM 3.

However PGM 2 called by PGM1 and PGM 3 called by PGM 2.

how we check that PGM 3 called by PGM 2 as we know only about the PGM 3. we don't about the other pgms.

Is there are command to check the stack of the PGM . Which PGM is called by which PGM without checking the Source code.

Thank you!
Mohd Wasim

Answer (score 2):

Check the QWVRCSTK API : [qwvrcstk API](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_71/apis/qwvrcstk.htm) ,  That's the equivalent of JOB information option 11=Display Call Stack

Example here : [RPGLE find Calling program name](http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/08/rpgle-find-calling-program-name-on.html)

Comment: Works only on the currently running program of course... if you want the whole stack, you can use  `DSPPGMREF PGM(OBJLIB/*ALL) OUTPUT(*OUTFILE) OBJTYPE(*PGM *SRVPGM *MODULE) OUTFILE(YOURBIB/PGMREF) `  , and perhaps use a recursive SQL query on the YOURLIB/PGMREF to get all the calling / callers programs

Answer (score 0):

While the program (PGM3) is active you can display it's call stack.  From WRKACTJOB screen place a "5=Work With" next to the entry, then from the next menu option "11=Display Call Stack".  The active program should be at (or near) the end of the list.

Of course that doesn't guarantee that is the only pathway the program can be called (that seems impossible to know without scanning the source, or a using change management utility).

Comment: Hi Richard, Thanks.. for your guidance .

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check this programatically, you can send a program message to the programs call stack entry.

```
SNDPGMMSG  MSG(' ') TOPGMQ(*SAME &PGMNAME) KEYVAR(&KEYVAR)
```

If you get a CPF2469 or CPF2479 message, the program is NOT on the call stack.

If you don't get an error, then the program is on the call stack.

You can use the &KEYVAR variable to remove the message you just sent off the message queue.